# What is performance penalty for using aggregates in C++?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

Consider this example with a structure `S` constructed and passed as an argument to a function:

```
struct S
{
    S() {}
    float vals[64];
};

inline S makeS() { return {}; }

void foo(const S &);

void bar() { foo( makeS() ); }
```

Looking at the assembly the compilers produce (https://godbolt.org/z/odoPr9836), it is pretty small (as expected).

But if we eliminate the constructor from `S` thus converting it in an aggregate (https://godbolt.org/z/qEWKbx5Ps), the assembly becomes many times more bulky.

It even seems that MSVC does not perform mandatory RVO and copies the aggregate:

```
...
movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx-128], xmm0
movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rax-96]
movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx-112], xmm1
movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rax-80]
...
```

Does it follow from this, that on practice the usage of aggregates produce much less optimal code compared to normal C++ classes or structures?

Comment: Relative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853659/can-copy-elision-be-perfomed-in-aggregate-initialization-in-c17
Aggregate initialization basically performs element-wise copy-initialization.

Comment: *"Does it follow..."* - No, it doesn't follow. You see a difference **only** because your comparison is unfair. **Aggregate-initialization** has to, by definition, have every member initialized. And those you don't provide for are recursively initialized from `{}`. That means you *asked* to zero out the array. To make a fair comparison try `inline S makeS() { S s; return s; }` as well, so default initialization is performed on your aggregate (and its sub-objects just as your c'tor does). C++ is overly expert friendly. An unpleasant truth, but there you have it.

Comment: The same as what? I see the same assembly with or without constructor when default initialization is forced. You still don't seem to be comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @StoryTeller i don't think that is doing the same. It's undefined behavior because you copy not yet initialized values, right?

Comment: Which is what the OP did with their constructor. Of course, is it formally an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion when the compiler does behind the scenes magic? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

**You comparison is unfair.**

---

```
struct S
{
    S() {}
    float vals[64];
};
```

With this, you didn't actually initialize `vals`. To make it a fair comparison, it should've been:

```
struct S
{
    S() : vals{} {}
    float vals[64];
};
```

Or simply use:

```
S() = default;
```

Now gcc and clang both produce identical code for them, where msvc produce the same code for `makeS`: https://godbolt.org/z/rezxTorGs

---

***Also someone please correct me:***

```
struct S
{
    float vals[64];
};

inline S makeS() { return {}; }
```

I believe this one uses default constructor instead of aggregate initialization.

You might need to use `return {{}};` or `return {.vals = {}};` to force aggregate initialization.

Comment: It's aggregate initialization still. No constructor call.